# changing the background colour of global navigation drop down

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, css, global-navigation

I want to change the background colour of global navigation drop down, for only one page.

can we use any CSS in script editor to achieve this ! Or change in master page to get change in all the pages !
Using SharePoint 2013 ent.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you need to change, just to verify

Comment: hi Derhalli,  there is slight change in question..  and i ll try to provide the ss...

Answer (score 2):

To change the color ONLY for the dropdowns in the navigation, use the below code:

```
.ms-core-listMenu-horizontalBox ul.dynamic{
   background-color: blue; /* add any color here */
}
```

Next reference the css using the below steps:

From site settings, choose Master Page, then click on Alternate CSS URL. Add the link to your CSS file.

Don't modify the master page as it's not recommended by Microsoft to modify master pages, so use the Alternate CSS method instead.

Comment: not getting your suggest path for Alternative CSS URL !!

Comment: In your site settings page, when you click on master pages link, there's an option to set alternate css.